# Получение информации из json vk и занесение ее в label

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, visual-studio-2017

Есть код:

```
//Получение информации профиля
        var request = new HttpRequest();
        string response = request.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/account.getProfileInfo?first_name,last_name,sex,relation,bdate,bdate_visibility,home_town,country,city,status,phone&access_token=" + token + "&v=5.92").ToString();
        // Получение json
        dynamic json = JObject.Parse(response);
        string name = json.first_name;
        string surname = json.last_name;
        label6.Text = name;
        label7.Text = surname;
```

Нужно получить имя и фамилию из json и перенести данные в `label6` и `label7`

Я создал переменные `name` и `surname` для хранения имени и фамилии, но при попытке присваивания значения выдает:[image: Исключение не обработано]

Сам json имеет вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используются `xNet` и `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`

Comment: А если так `string name = json.response.first_name;`? Приведите лучше сам json текстом, а не непонятную картинку

Comment: @АндрейNOP Все равно не получается. Вот JSON: http://pasted.co/713d52f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сути JSON можно распарсить двумя способами:

1. `JObject` - Метод чтения из строки `Parse`. Суть работы с `JObject` в том, что вы работаете по аналогии со словарем, указывая напрямую, текстовым значением необходимый ключ.
   Пример:

   ```
   var json = JObject.Parse("{\"success\" : \"true\"}");
   var status = (bool) json["success"];
   ```
2. `JsonConvert` - Метод чтения из строки `DeserializeObject`. Здесь суть в том, что вы сразу преобразуете в нужный тип все ваши данные и обращаетесь к созданным свойствам.
   Пример:

   ```
   class Status 
   {
       public bool Success { get; set; }
   }
   //...
   var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status>("{\"success\" : \"true\"}");
   var status = json.Success;
   ```

Теперь зная все это давайте взглянем на ваши попытки:

```
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(response);
string name = json.first_name;
```

Используете `JObject`, хорошо, но помним что к нему обычно обращаются по ключу, вы же используете свойство (о котором десериализатор по сути нечего не знает).

Если хотите использовать `JObject` - обращайтесь по ключу к нужному значению.
Если хотите использовать свойства - создайте класс, в котором вы прописываете необходимые свойства и используйте `JsonConvert`.

Answer (score 0):

выдает исключение - в `dinamic` нет поля/свойства с таким именем
как минимум используй `var` вместо `dinamic` - будет легче понять с чем ты работаешь
вот общий RegEx: https://regex101.com/r/GYNkSs/2
вот это выделит из json только те два поля: https://regex101.com/r/GYNkSs/3

вот что хорошего для своего проекта ты можешь сделать:

- не писать логику в методе обработки события (может подвесить форму). в `WPF` это намного легче делается
- использовать библиотеку REST-запросов (`RestSharp` например) или VK API библиотеку (она сама умеет работать с web-api)

вот еще один вариант RegEx: https://regex101.com/r/GYNkSs/4 в нем можно яснее увидеть какое значение что означает

Comment: Вот что происходит при использовании var: https://prnt.sc/lpmfe3. Вот видео с которого я все "списываю": https://youtu.be/460UCCmscwk?t=354. Вроде делаю все так же. JSON: http://pasted.co/713d52f1

Comment: Можно уточнить? "Не писать логику в методе обработки события", т.е. не присваивать значения переменным или имелось ввиду что-то другое?

Comment: при использовании `var` не дает компилироваться - все верно, исправь

Comment: "Не писать логику в методе обработки события" - оставь в нем только асинхронные методы для начала

Comment: посмотри библиотеку VK api в NuGet - станет намного проще с api работать